# How to centre div inside of a circle button using css

Tags: html, css

I want to create a button with an x that is centred inside of a circle border. How can I centre the x vertically and horizontally inside of the circle?
I'm open to a different way of doing it than the code I have provided.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you

https://codepen.io/glittergirl/pen/xybOzL

```
#mdiv {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mdiv {
  height:25px;
  width:3px;
  background-color: #000;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
  Z-index:1;
}

.md {
  height:25px;
  width:3px;
  background-color:#000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
          transform: rotate(90deg);
  Z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use centering with `left&top: 50%` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`

See this codepen for an example.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vVEKbV

Answer (score 0):

Try this a simple and less code version.

```css
.circle-button {
 border-radius: 100%;
 border: 3px solid #000;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 20px 30px;
 font-size: 50px;
}

.circle-button:after {
 content: "\274c";
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-button"></div>
```